# override relation in Laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel, eloquent, relation

I am working on limiting access depending on user roles.

I want to be able to somehow override a belongsToMany relation to return all, if user->isAdmin() returns true.

Currently have as the AccountController index method:

```
public function index()
{
    if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())   // can this go in beforeFilter? 
        return Account::all();
    else
        return Auth::user()->accounts;
}
```

in my User model:

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("Account");
}
```

Is there a neat way to do this without needing an if statement in the controller functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You cannot do this.

The relation method must return an instance of `Relation`, [otherwise it throws an error](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2409-L2413).

---

There's nothing stopping you from creating a separate method for this:

**AccountController.php**:

```php
public function index()
{
    return Auth::user()->userAccounts();
}
```

**User.php**:

```php
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("Account");
}

public function userAccounts()
{
    if ($this->isAdmin()) return Account::all();

    return $this->accounts;
}
```